# Circuits while solving linear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

I have come across this Kirchoff's laws problem where I am supposed to find the currents. I came across this while solving/dealing with systems of linear equations and don't know much about circuits.

[image]

However, I have tried, based on my very limited knowledge of the subject-matter, to come up with the following:
Am I faltering somewhere? Or is everything wrong?

According to Kirchoff's laws

$$I_1+I_3=I_2\Rightarrow I_1-I_2+I_3=0$$ $$(V+12)/4-(V-24)/12+V/8=0$$
$$V/4-V/12+V/8=-12/4-24/12=-5$$
$$(7V)/12=-5\Rightarrow V=-60/7$$
$$I_1=(V+12)/4=((-60/7)+12)/4$$
$$I_2=(V-24)/24=(-60/7-12)/24$$
$$I_3=V/8=-60/7/8$$

Comment: If your question is about circuits, ask it here https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Your math is wrong at least in one place. $V/4-V/12+V/8=\frac V{24}(6-2+3)=\frac{7V}{24}$

Comment: Thanks. The method?